# the whole DAY/ the whole

Tags: meaning

I was told that 1 is correct:

> 1 Yesterday, I spent the whole day working.

But 2 is wrong:

> 2 Last week, I spent the whole days working.

Is 2 wrong? Any explanation why it is wrong?

Comment: Do you mean you *spent every day working the whole day*?  If so, then that's how to correct it.  If you mean you *spent whole days working*, but not necessarily every day, then use that.  You can't use "the whole" with a plural noun. You have to remove "the".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(2) is not idiomatic. You can't use *the whole of* with a plural. You would have to say *the whole week* or *the whole of each day.*